# Execute method/function from browser and vice versa?

Tags: vb.net, cefsharp

I'm currently using CefSharp 111.2.20 for WinForms. I have the browser load up my html/css page. I want to be able to click on an element on the page and have that element execute js code to run a function in my vb.net code.

I've been looking online and it seems like I have to use `browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register`.

However, even after checking ObjectRepository is bound with `browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.IsBound("hello")`, nothing happens when I click on my bnutton.

```
Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

    CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = True
    browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = True
    browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("hello", New DotNetMessage(), False, Nothing)

    Me.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    browser.Width = 230

    AddHandler browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged, AddressOf IsBrowserInit

End Sub
    Private Sub IsBrowserInit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        browser.Load("index.html")

        If browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.IsBound("hello") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Bound")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Bound")
        End If
    End Sub

Public Class DotNetMessage
    Public Sub ShowMsg(Message As String)
        MessageBox.Show(Message)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is a simple html page with the button

```
<head>
    <script>
function ShowDotNetMessage(){
    hello.show("Hello World");
}
    </script>
</head>
<input type="button" id="myButton" onclick="ShowDotNetMessage();" value="Click Me">
```

Nothing happens when I click on the button.

Anyone able to get this to work? Or what about the other way around, where I can call a JS function from vb.net?

Comment: You have show and ShowMsg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **DotNetMessage** class has a **ShowMsg** method, yet you are calling **show** in `JavaScript`. The method in `JavaScript` should be **showMsg**.

```js
function ShowDotNetMessage(){
    hello.showMsg("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: I found that I could also use Cefsharp.PostMessage as if its an inbuilt function.